# How to capture Ctrl-V or enable Right Click Paste option with the KeyDown event of a TextBox in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, keyboard-shortcuts

I am trying to paste an image in TextBox on either user presses Ctrl + V shortcut or right-click and select paste option.
I tried this method to capture the keyboard key but it only works if I enter V

```
if(e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.V)
```

How to capture Ctrl + V both keyboard keys. In my case, this is not working

```
if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.V && e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Control)
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to capture the control key, you need to check the `HasFlag` property.

```
var controlDown = Window.Current.CoreWindow.GetKeyState(VirtualKey.Control).HasFlag(CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down);
    
if (controlDown & e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.V)
{
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any way to also capture right-click and select paste option in uwp?

Comment: By default, textBox has enabled the right-click paste option for copied text but if I copying the image in clipboard then it is not showing that option.

Comment: TextBox does not support paste image, please try to use RichEditBox

Comment: RichEditBox will break my existing functionalities. Is there any other way?

Comment: Yep, May be you could make custom control that place new image control cover textbox with specific position when paste image.

Comment: is there any example available?

Comment: You could use the Canvas as the root container, When Ctrl + V pressed, make new image and insert it into Canvas with specific Canvas Left and Top value.